# Updating WPF MainWindow from an async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wpf

Is this an acceptable approach to update WPF MainWindow from an async task, using events thrown from a public static class?

- In MainWindow.cs, I subscribe to  `UI.TaskCompleted` event
- In UI.cs, I subscribe to `AsyncTaskActions.TaskCompleted` event

Using this pattern, `AsyncTaskActions.TaskCompleted` is raised when an async task is completed.  UI catch the event and raise `UI.TaskCompleted`.  This way, the event is caught in `MainWindow` where I can use `Displacher.Invoke` to refresh the displayed page.  The end result is I get a page refresh when a task is completed and the task still runs asychronously.

Application design summary:

- **MainWindow**: main window which can have several different page classes in content area within the main window.
- **Common.cs**  public static class contains a number of common methods through the UI in the application.
- **AsyncTaskActions.cs** - class with a number of async common methods (i.e. download file)

Code snippets:

```
    public partial class MainWindow 
        public MainWindow()
        {    
           UI.TaskCompleted += UI_TaskCompleted; 
        }

        void UI_TaskCompleted(EventArgs e)
        {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(this.PageRefresh));
        }

       public void PageRefresh()        
       {
           var page = ((ContentArea)).Content;
           if (page == null) return;

            //if (page.GetType().Name == "")
            switch (page.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "SearchPage":
                    ((SearchPage) page).SearchParts();
                    break;
                case "LegoPartPage":
                    ((LegoPartPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "LegoSetPage":
                    ((LegoSetPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "MainPage":
                    ((MainPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "MiniFigPage":
                    ((MiniFigPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
            }
        }
   }

    public static class UI
    {
       public delegate void TaskComplete(EventArgs e);
       public static event TaskComplete TaskCompleted;

        public static async Task<int> DownloadPriceSummaryAsync(String itemNo, Int64 colorId)
        {
            var wAsyncTaskClasses = new AsyncTaskClasses();
            wAsyncTaskClasses.TaskCompleted += wAsyncTaskClasses_TaskCompleted;
            Task<HtmlDocument> task = wAsyncTaskClasses.DownloadPriceGuide(string.Format(Common.BrickLinkPrice, itemNo, colorId), itemNo, colorId);
            return await  wAsyncTaskClasses.ParsePriceSummaryAsync(task, itemNo, colorId);
        }
 }


public class AsyncTaskActions
{
    public delegate void TaskComplete(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event TaskComplete TaskCompleted;

    public async Task<int> ParsePriceSummaryAsync(Task<HtmlDocument> task, string itemNo, Int64 colorId)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => ParsePriceSummary(task, itemNo, colorId));
    }

    public int ParsePriceSummary(Task<HtmlDocument> task, string itemNo, Int64 colorId)
    {


        if (null != TaskCompleted)
        {
            TaskCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        return recordCount;
    }
```

Comment: Cross-posted to Stack Overflow: [C# How to efficently update WPF MainWindow from an async task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344061/c-sharp-how-to-efficently-update-wpf-mainwindow-from-an-async-task)

Comment: I would not suggest leaving this in your code in the question `... some code....`. Either provide the code or just remove this line, it makes your code look incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into MVVM, then your async task will operate on the ViewModel and not the UI element. Then WPF will update the UI when it deem fit.

I like Caliburn.Micro for the MVVM parts

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro